# Regression factors and covariance matrix

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to follow someone else's notes. They have two matrices.

One is called `comfact` (company factors). This is a 580 x 5 matrix. The 580 rows represent 580 different companies. The 5 columns represent 5 betas for the 5 different factors that were used to model a companies growth rate. These beta's were calculated by OLS regression.

The second matrix is called `covmatrix`. It is a 5 x 5 covariance matrix of the 5 factors above.

There is line in the notes (below) which I'm not sure what it is doing and what the result is showing me?

```
comfact * covmatrix * comfact'
```